# PC suddenly shuts off and cannot boot anymore

Tags: boot, power-supply, shutdown

I suddenly have an issue with my PC that when I use my PC it suddenly shuts off and my power supply that is Corsair AX1200i turns red light.

To fix that issue I keep opening the case and pushing the cables in to make sure it's not loose. When I turn it on it's fine again.  Then on any random day or time it does it again and I do the steps I did before but now it happened again and I did the same thing I have been doing for many months it did not work.

The PC turns on and then it turns off after few seconds and then it turns on again and turns off and off in a loop by itself and the Q CODE goes up to 7F and there is orange light and shuts off and automatically turn on.

Computer Specs:

Power supply: Corsair AX1200i

Motherboard : ROG MAXIMUS X HERO (WI-FI AC)

BIOS version : 1801

RAM: GSkill f4 -3400C16-16TZ

Processor:Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3696 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)

Comment: Generally when troubleshooting hardware, you need to try changing parts , In your case it looks suspiciously power related, you should try changing power supply. You could meddle with testing the power supply, backprobing with a multimeter and that would pick up some subset of a power supply being very bad but passing that test doesn't mean it's good. But better and easier is to change PSU. You can't troubleshoot without redundant parts.

Comment: I've read the most part of this thread (https://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=112526) on a Corsair forum, and though it's dated, there's a lot of info in there. Do you use a surge protector? It seems to be one of the reasons why your PSU could have failed you, don't really know why. Seems those boxes operate on a very narrow set of of characteristics. Have you self-tested it, and if so, does it at least pass the self-test? You could try a different PSU, even a less powerful one, just to rule out other reasons, such as bad RAM, non-supported OC, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Something must be incorrectly connected or malfunctionning. It might be because of the light function.

I encountered this once and it was due to the CPU fan incorrectly plugged on CPU_OPT on the motherboard while i was using a Fractal watercooling CPU fan with no lightning function. Plugging it to the CPU_fan instead solved the issue.